# How to pass a lookup field value from child comp to parent comp by lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components

there is one user lookup field in a modal , I want select one user from that field and on click of a submit button I want pass that selected user value to another form which has same user lookup field. please tell me how to do it?
[image]

Comment: If you could add code which will help us to answer better.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Based on what you've shared, we don't have enough information to help you. Including your code as well as an explanation of how these components work together would be useful for starters. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from child component to parent component by dispatching custom event.

**child.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-input class="slds-m-around_medium" type="text" label="Enter Name" lwc:ref="name"></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button type="button" label="Send Name" onclick={sendName}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

**child.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
export default class Child extends LightningElement {
      
    sendName(){
      let name = this.refs?.name?.value;
      const childDataEvent = new CustomEvent("childdata", { detail: name });

      // Dispatches the event.
      this.dispatchEvent(childDataEvent);
    }
}
```

In child component data we are dispatching event `childdata` with data and we will handle this in parent component.

**parent.html**

```
<template>
      <lightning-card>
            <p>Name: {name}</p>
           <c-child onchilddata={handleChildData}></c-child>
     </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**parent.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
      name = '';
      handleChildData(event) {
            this.name = event.detail;
     }
}
```

In Parent component we are handling `childData` event which was dispatched from child component. We created handler for event  like this `onchilddata={handleChildData}`.

**Reference:**

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-from-child-to-parent
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/events-create-dispatch.html